# Magento Product Import XML/CSV 5 description columns to one description field

Tags: magento-1.8, product, import

I have an a little bit crazy feature request. I have a Excel/CSV file with 5 description fields. Description 1, Description 2, Description 3 ... and need during the import to merge them with breakline

Description 1
Description 2
Description 3
Description 4
Description 5

into one description field.

I know via PHP is it possible but the guy who needs this want it so simple as possible via CSV or better Excel.

Comment: Not much to do with Magento, oder?

Comment: I know but i need this as simple solution like this. The guy wants to upload the import data as CSV or MS Excel XML file and it needs to merge during the import progress more than 1 columns into 1 description column with breaklines. I prefer a quick and easy solution because i don't want write a extension for that.

Answer (score 1):

So it is not really a quick solution but you could look into building something using [FastSimple Import](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport)

This would allow you to build your own product converter where you can merge the fields you need into the description field and then pass this into the importer. I have been working with this extension on a couple of products and highly recommend it when building custom import mappings.

Answer (score -1):

Use Excel formule ---> Text ---> Merge fields

Comment: That is what the guy doesn't want. He wants to upload the data file with the 5 fields and merge then during the import progress. Maybe possible with Magento Dataflow and additional XML actions?